# Confusion about object companion after using Laravel factory()->create()

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting strange results when comparing the object returned from the factory()->create() method. The below php artisan tinker paste shows what I am experiencing.

```
>>> $game1 = factory(App\Game::class)->create();
=> App\Game {#2909
     title: "Macey Rogahn",
     image_location: "Julio Hoppe/fake/path/image.img",
     updated_at: "2018-08-29 02:45:40",
     created_at: "2018-08-29 02:45:40",
     id: 10,
   }
>>> $game2 = App\Game::first();
=> App\Game {#2906
     id: 10,
     created_at: "2018-08-29 02:45:40",
     updated_at: "2018-08-29 02:45:40",
     title: "Macey Rogahn",
     image_location: "Julio Hoppe/fake/path/image.img",
   }
>>> $game1 == $game2
=> false
```

I don't understand why this result is false. The values are equal, yet php is returning false on the comparison. This is also causing me issues using Collection->diff() during testing. I'm only average at PHP, can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even both objects refer to the same domain model they are instantiated in a different way and therefore, from the PHP point of view, they are different objects.

You can easily spot this by looking at tinker output. Even both have a property `id` with value 10, they have different PHP object id (#2909 and #2906)

When you are calling `App\Game::first()`, Eloquent connects to the database, fetch the data, **creates a new object** and then hydrates (fills) the object properties with the database values. Since you are (well, Eloquent is) creating a new object, they are not the same instance.

When you compare objects (`==`) PHP is not aware of they being Eloquent models but just normal PHP objects and they don't point to the same area of memory.

If you want to compare models equality then you must compare their ID, or create specific logic in your base model, for instance

```
// file: App/Model.php
abstract class Model extends Eloquent {

    public function isSameAs(\App\Model $model):bool {
        return $this->id !== null and $this->id === $model->id;
    }
}

// file: App/Game.php
class Game extends Model {

}
```

The you could do

```
$game1->isSameAs($game2);
```

Note I used `isSameAs()` instead of `isEqualTo()` intentionally because you are not comparing every property of the models and therefore even they have the same ID they may not be equal models.